# How to create a list of Textviews

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview, textview

I'm wanting a list of clickable textviews this is the xml I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/marque_scrolling_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Create a Marquee (Scrolling Text) in Android Using TextView. Android Marquee (Scrolling Text) Tutorial with Example"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Would like a list of items all clickable

This is the code I'm using:

```
TextView marque1 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.marque_scrolling_text);
marque1.setSelected(true);

marque1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        System.out.println("dhgjgf jfgsfjhsgfsjfgdfjh");
    }
});
```

Is this possible?

Comment: use ListView widget of android https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Comment: But cant marquee with Listview + having hard time in changing the text colour.

Comment: Why can't you use marquee with list view? And what problem are you having with changing text color?

Comment: Unsure - seemed to try several things to get it to marquee . Have you any working code.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use ListView then you can dynamically create and add the TextViews yourself!

I assume you have an array of Strings you want to show as TextViews:

```
String[] strings = {"TextA", "TextB"};
```

Get the Layout that will contain all the TextViews:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.listLayout);
// you will need to set an id for the layout in the xml
```

Then iterate through the list, create a new TextView for each String, add the onClickListener and do whatever you want with it (like changing text colour), and then add it to the Layout:

```
for(String s : strings)
{
     TextView newTextView = new TextView(this);
     newTextView.setText(s);
     newTextView.setTextColor(#0066ff); // for example
     newTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  
        { 
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v)
            { 
              System.out.println("dhgjgf jfgsfjhsgfsjfgdfjh");
            } 
        }); 

     layout.addView(newTextView);
}
```